# Error: invalid_client on signin with google+ API quick start app for php

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

I am trying to create an Google+ API When am I doing this i got this Error: invalid_client message I think I followed the instructions well ( https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php ).  When I click on the sign in button the popup has the error Error: invalid_client and the Below given Request Details.

Request Details:

```
cookie_policy_enforce=false
response_type=code token id_token gsession
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
redirect_uri=postmessage
access_type=offline
cookie_policy=single_host_origin
proxy=oauth2relay818254346
origin=http://collage.bluecoresys.com
state=1266385007|0.1542964471
client_id={{ CLIENT_ID }}
request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity
authuser=0
```

Any one have any solution regarding this then kindly let me know as soon as possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace the value of `client_id` with the Client ID that you generate in Step 1 of the quickstart instructions.

Comment: i did this but after signin my APP is open and when i click on accept button, nothing is happening ???. i want to import my all google+ pictures to my website with this API .how i do this could you provide me any link or code for thi  ?